# How to use a vector of struct with a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a vector with the type struct, and within the struct another vector, I want to be able to print the content, but I don't know how.

```
using namespace std;

struct graph{
    vector<int> a;
};
vector< graph > g;

int main(){
    g[1].a.push_back(3);
    g[1].a.push_back(4);

    cout << g[1].a[0];


    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: `g[1]` is undefined behavior because `g` is empty.

Comment: @aschepler If I write "g.push_back(1); then g[0].a.pb(3); " It wouldn't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access elements of an empty vector.

```
int main(){
    // Push back new graph
    g.push_back(graph());

    // Vector now has 1 element at index 0
    g[0].a.push_back(1);

    // Adding new element
    g.push_back(graph());

    cout << g[0].a[0];
    cout << g[1].a[0];
    return 0;
}
```

> Result: 12

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're trying to index an empty vector.

`g[1].a.push_back(3);`

You haven't yet added any elements to g, so this should be giving a compile error.

You could possibly write it like this:

```
int main(){

    // declare and instantiate an object first
    graph gr;
    gr.a.push_back( 3 );

    // use the push_back() function on the entire vector, rather than an element
    g.push_back( gr );

    // now you can index both vectors
    cout << g[0].a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `g[1]` is undefined behavior, not ill-formed, so it's not true this "should be giving a compile error". And I would be surprised if any compilers did notice an issue at compile time, since this would require understanding the meanings and relationships between the `vector` default constructor and `operator[]`, which are individually valid function uses.